# Как добавить кнопку NSButton в NSTokenField?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Я хочу в своем приложении в поле NSTokenField добавить кнопку, например что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е в NSTokenField есть кнопка плюсик которая должна выполнять какое-то действие, например всплывающее меню с выбором token'ов которые можно добавить в поле NSTokenField.

Я создал кнопку программно и добавил её в NSTokenField:

```
NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(185, -1, 19, 24)];
[button setTitle:@"<"];
[button setFont:[NSFont menuFontOfSize:[NSFont smallSystemFontSize]]];
[button setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
[button setBezelStyle:NSSmallSquareBezelStyle];
[button setTarget:self];
[button setAction:@selector(action:)];
[formatTokenField addSubview:button];
```

кнопка добавилась нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но когда я пытаюсь ввести символы в NSTokenField область ввода перекрывает мою кнопку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйсто разобраться как правильно надо добавлять кнопки в NSTokenField и что нужно сделать чтобы область ввода не перекрывала добавленные кнопки (не могли бы вы привести примеры кода). Всем заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно мне не понятен замысел и предложение неправильное. Но почему бы просто не разместить эту кнопку рядом?

```
NSRect tfFrame = formatTokenField.frame;
CGFloat btnWidth = 19.0f;
NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(tfFrame.origin.x + tfFrame.size.width - 1, tfFrame.origin.y - 1, btnWidth, tfFrame.size.height + 2)];
...
[[self view] addSubview:button]; //view  на котором formatTokenField
```

Ну либо если хотите именно так, то Вам нужно унаследоваться от `NSTokenFieldCell` и переопределить функцию `drawingRectForBounds`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ExtCell : NSTokenFieldCell
@end

@implementation ExtCell

- (NSRect) drawingRectForBounds:(NSRect)rect {
    CGFloat vIndent = 2; //отступ сверху
    CGFloat hIndent = 2; // отступ сбоку
    CGFloat tfWidth = 185; //ширина поля ввода (ширина TokenField за вычетом отступов, ширины кнопки и прочего по усмотрению)
    CGFloat tfHeight = 20; //высота поля ввода (высота TokenField за вычетом отступов и прочего по усмотрению)
    NSRect newRect = CGRectMake(hIndent, vIndent, tfWidth, tfHeight);
    return newRect;
}

@end
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения `vIndent` и другие поменяйте на нормальные для своего случая.

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]